# phpmyadmin not working after mysql update

Tags: mysql, permissions, update

i followed [this](https://wiki.ampath.or.ke/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=70811889) guide to update my mysql form 5.1 to 5.5. After lots and lots of command and headache, i was able to upgrade mysql. i checked the version via terminal.

But now there is another problem. phpmyadmin is not working. It says

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

i searched everywher and tried various solutions like including `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` in `apache2.conf` file and restared apache(it started showing 404 error). But it's still not working.

i remember the terminal was showing `phpmyadmin is broken or not fully installed`, while i was trying various solutions.

Also now when i open terminal(Ctrl + Alt +t), it shows various errors:

```
Command 'uname' is available in '/bin/uname'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
uname: command not found
bash: [: !=: unary operator expected
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
Command 'sed' is available in '/bin/sed'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
sed: command not found
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
ubc-7@ubc-7-desktop:~$
```

What should i do now? repair, reinstall, format??

Comment: try do a reinstall should fix any issues.